# Автоприём звонка работает только при открытом приложении

Tags: java, android, broadcast-receiver

Код реализует индикацию состояния телефона и автоприём звонка
но часть кода, отвечающая за автоприём работает только при развёрнутом приложении, хотя индикация работает даже при закрытом приложении.
где я ошибся ?

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        final PhoneStateListener listener = new PhoneStateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                switch (state)
                {
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Call Ended..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.i("stop", "Call Ended....");
                        break;
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Call Picked..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();
                        //Log.i("received", "Call Picked....");

                        break;
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                        // Вот здесь надо обрабатывать звонок
                        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Call RingingBEOCH..." + incomingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        try {
                            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input keyevent " +
                                    Integer.toString(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));

                        } catch (IOException e) {

                        }
                        break;
                }

            }
        };
        telephonyManager.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
```

ниже приведен манифест

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".CallReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


</application>
```

Comment: Покажите свой манифест

Comment: добавил манифест в вопрос

Comment: С манифестом все ок. Не пробовали поставить лог в `catch(IOEXception e)`?

Comment: не понял, что вы имели в виду?

Comment: Вставьте `Log.e("stop", "Call ringing", e);` в блок где ловится исключение

Comment: попробовал
но безуспешно, все равно даже при простом сворачивании не срабатывает

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68023/discussion-between-barmaley-and-sqlbastard1613).